# Why static const member function of template class can not appear in constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a template classes like below

```
typedef void (*single_tick_data_handler) (DCF77::tick_t decoded_data);
typedef void (*flush_handler) ();
template <single_tick_data_handler process_single_tick_data, flush_handler flush>
struct DCF77_Demodulator : public Binning::Convoluter<uint16_t, 100> {
    // details omitted
}

template <typename Frequency_Control> struct DCF77_Clock_Controller {
    static void process_single_tick_data(const DCF77::tick_t tick_data) {
        // some code
    }
    static void flush() {
        // more code
    }

    static DCF77_Demodulator<process_single_tick_data, flush> Demodulator;
}
```

Now if I try to instantiate the template like

```
DCF77_Clock_Controller<DCF77_Frequency_Control> foo;
```

the compiler will complain.

```
-I/home/udo/Desktop/arduino-1.6.0/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x -I/home/udo/Desktop/arduino-1.6.0/libraries/dcf77 /tmp/build3762783334603310985.tmp/Swiss_Army_Debug_Helper.cpp -o /tmp/build3762783334603310985.tmp/Swiss_Army_Debug_Helper.cpp.o 
In file included from Swiss_Army_Debug_Helper.ino:19:0:
/home/udo/Desktop/arduino-1.6.0/libraries/dcf77/dcf77.h: In instantiation of 'struct DCF77_Clock_Controller<DCF77_Frequency_Control>':
Swiss_Army_Debug_Helper.ino:711:29:   required from here
/home/udo/Desktop/arduino-1.6.0/libraries/dcf77/dcf77.h:1897:63: error: 'static void DCF77_Clock_Controller<Frequency_Control>::process_single_tick_data(DCF77::tick_t) [with Frequency_Control = DCF77_Frequency_Control]' cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static DCF77_Demodulator<process_single_tick_data, flush> Demodulator;
```

Of course process_single_tick_data must be a constant expression if I want to use it as a template parameter. But as soon as I instantiate the Clock Controller the process_single_tick data should be resolvable at compile time. The compiler even explains to me in its error message how this template is resolved. So I would assume that this static member function is a valid argument to pass to the DCF77_Demodulator template. Unfortunately the compiler disagrees. But why? What am I missing?

Comment: You are writing  [tag:c++03], aren't you? `DCF77_Demodulator<& DCF77_Clock_Controller::process_single_tick_data, & DCF77_Clock_Controller::flush> Demodulator` and it will work (I'll leave it up to some other [tag:language-lawyer] to answer why you need that (I'm lazy)).

Comment: @Filip Roséen - refp: The `&` is not required with static members. In this case it seems to be a name resolution issue, not a "`&` is required" issue. E.g. this `DCF77_Demodulator<DCF77_Clock_Controller::process_single_tick_data, DCF77_Clock_Controller::flush> Demodulator;` also compiles GCC in pre-C++11 modes.

Comment: @AnT I'm well aware of such fact, the important bit lies in making it a *qualified-name* - I just wrote that mini-snippet directly from my head, and I'm one of those *"weird"* people who likes to explicitly say that we are dealing with a pointer-to-function, and not a reference.

Comment: @Filip Roséen - refp: I'm just saying it to help any prospective language-lawyer to explain it. Frankly, to me it looks like a compiler defect. A quick experiment with GCC shows that unqualified name lookup works fine for static data members (in the same context), but for some reason fails to work for static member functions. I could be missing something though.

Comment: The issue is only triggered when the surrounding class is also a template. E.g. if we change `DCF77_Clock_Controller` to a non-template class, the issue will disappear.

Comment: My compiler identifies itself as: arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors (Arduino build)) 4.8.3 20140228 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 208322]
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc. I tried the & trick but this had no impact. The compiler still refuses to deal with the code. And yes, if I make the clock controller a none template class the issue disappears. Unfortunately I need it templated.

Comment: Did you try @AnT's suggestion of qualifying the scope of the method?

Comment: @Udo Klein: The point is that it is not about "& trick". It is specifically about using *qualified names*. GCC reports exactly the same error as yours for unqualified names and the error disappears once qualified names are used. It would be strange to see it behave differently in ARM builds.

Comment: I second what @AnT wrote above, the trick lies in using qualified-id's (and not unqualified); the added ampersand has no effect in this case.

Comment: OK, now it works. However I do not fully get it. Why is it DCF77_Clock_Controller::process_single_tick_data instead of DCF77_Clock_Controller<DCF77_Frequency_Control>::process_single_tick_data? I am confused.

Comment: @Udo Klein: Inside the template class definition you can use a "short" version of the name - just the template name without the parameters - to refer to the "current" specialization of the the template. I.e. inside the `DCF77_Clock_Controller` definition just saying `DCF77_Clock_Controller` is equivalent to saying `DCF77_Clock_Controller<Frequency_Control>`. Note that this is different from saying `DCF77_Clock_Controller<DCF77_Frequency_Control>`. The latter would refer to a specific specialization of the template, while the former refers to the "current" specialization.